# Array isn't being seen by function.. storing in variable a no-no?

Tags: php, variables, scope

I've googled around and didn't see the answer. I have an array I'm storing in a variable that I'm trying to pass to a function..

```
$myArr = 'array('item1', 'item2')';

require('script.php'); //where actual function is

makeCode($myArr);
```

When I use makeCode(array('item1', 'item2')); it works fine.. I've even tried to add `global $myArr` to `makeCode`, but that didn't work either.

I'm thinking it's a scope problem, but maybe I'm misusing the string. print_r($myArr) prints properly, it just isn't passing or something.

The function basically just compares $myArr values and if it matches what's in the function's array, it outputs the correct HTML, so I didn't list it. It works, just not the variable.. Thanks!

```
--makeCode()--
 function makeCode($listArr){
 /* global $myArr; //Tried this */
   $output = '';
   $items = array(
      'item1'        =>  "Code for item1",
      'item2'         =>  "Code for item2"
       )
   /* $myArr = $listArr; //tried this too */
        foreach ($listArr as $val) {
            if(array_key_exists($val, $items)){
                if(strlen($output)>0) $output .="|"; //Add Sytnax
                $output .="$items[$val]";
            }
        }
  }
```

That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$myArr = 'array('item1', 'item2')';
```

$myArr is a string here. I'm not sure that's what you meant. Try:

```
$myArr = array('item1', 'item2');
```

If this is what you meant then this will behave differently than calling

```
makeCode(array('item1', 'item2'));
```

Because this is calling using an actual array.

Comment: Ah, I see. By doing that, it only loads the first item from the $myArr. What I need $myArr to do is output `array('item1', 'item2')` inside, just like it is on the last line in your post.

Comment: It does print Array ( [0] => item1 [1] => item2 ) however. Would I have to format this array? They're on the same page I just wanted to keep it up top with the rest of the overrides.

Comment: @kcdwayne I'm not sure I follow, maybe you could add the code for `makeCode` to your question along with what output you expect?

Comment: Sure. I've updated with the function. I'm just trying to get $myArr to work in makeCode() as makeCode($myArr) being the same as if I used makeCode(array('item1', 'item2')); . Right now the output completely disappears. (or just prints value 0 and skips the rest)

Comment: @kcdwayne There's a small bug in your method: `foreach ($listArr as $val)` is using `$listArr` but the start of the method uses `$listArray`

Comment: Just a typo. The function just compares 2 arrays and prints the ones that are in both with the function arrays values.. the function works, 100%.. just not passing an array as a variable. I need it to print `array('item1', 'item2')` inside of makeCode(). When I use `makeCode(array('item1', 'item2'))`, it works. When I use `makeCode($myArr);`, I get nothing if $myArr='array('x1',x2')', and only the 1st value if I use $myArr = array('x1','x2');*in the output. print_r($myArr) prints correctly. Names are bogus, the actual coding is quite long...

Comment: **`$myArr=array('x1','x2');` only passes 1st value to output.

Comment: `$myArr = array('x1','x2');` will work differently than using `makeCode(array('item1', 'item2'))` because the arrays are different. The makeCode method only adds to output if the value exists in `$items` keys. `$items` doesn't have `x1` or `x2`.

Comment: Forget the name of the variable values/function keys. They're just for demonstration, item1, x1, its universal. (I get what you're saying but the names are correct in the real code.) The problem is that `$myArr = array('value1', 'value2')` ONLY passes value1 into the $output. If I use 'print_r($myArr)', all values show (which is good, the array works, but the $output only sees the first value.) I'm sorry if this is confusing. I'm just trying to figure out why making `$myArr = 'array('1', '2')'` breaks the code, and your suggestion only passes the 1st value of `$myArr` to `makeCode()`..

Comment: @kcdwayne To be clear. There is no difference between calling: `$myArr = array('item1', 'item2'); makeCode($myArr);` and calling `makeCode(array('item1', 'item2'))`. No need to apologise, I'm happy to help. Using `$myArr = 'array('1', '2')'` will break the code because in that case `$myArr` is not an array. It is a string.

Comment: I apologize.. apparently something has went wrong inside of the function because even the original method is failing now.. I'd say your suggestion is the answer something has just failed in the function. It's only passing one value now as well.

Comment: #palmface. I had a closing brace in the wrong place at right before return. Thanks for the help - I understand what you mean now about it passing as a string. I thought it would be translated correctly because it was passing FROM a string. Works perfectly now - thanks again!